# how to improve the performance on this type of Query?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle11g

I have query that I am searching for a range of user accounts but every time I pass query I will be using multiple id number's first 5 digits and based on that I will searching. I wanted to know is there any other way to re-write this query for user Id range when we use more than 10 userIDs to search? Is there going to be huge performance hit with this kind of search in query?

### example:

```
select A.col1,B.col2,B.col3
from table1 A,table2 B
where A.col2=B.col2
and (B.col_id like '12345%' 
OR B.col_id like '47474%' 
OR B.col_id like '59598%');
```

I am using Oracle11g.

Comment: "how to avoid using OR in sql query?" this is the wrong question. Right question: "How can I improve the performance of this query?". Don't pick some arbitrary thing in your query and decide to make it go away.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong necessarily with using `OR` in a query. However I would recommend not use pre ANSI 92 join syntax. instead of `from table1 A, Table2 B` use `FROM table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.Col2 = B.col2`

Comment: create a temp table with your search values and join it properly, it would clean up the ugly

Comment: What is `C.col_id` in your query? Did you miss one more table?

Comment: Sorry,its b.col_id all the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is not important how many UserIDs you will pass to the query. The most considerable part is what is selectivity of your query. In other words: how many rows will return your query and how many rows are there in your tables. If the number of returned rows is relatively small then it is good idea to create an index on column `B.col_id`. There is also nothing bad in using `OR` condition. Basically each `OR` will add one more `INDEX RANGE SCAN`  to the execution plan with final `CONCATENATION` (but you'd rather check your actual plan to be sure). If the total cost of all that operations are lower than full table scan then Oracle CBO will use your index. In other case if you select >=20-30% of data at once then full table scan is most likely to happen and you should even less be worried about `OR` because all data will be read and comparing each value with your multiple conditions won't add much overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the use of LIKE makes it impossible for Oracle to use indexes.

If the query is going to be reused, consider creating a synthetic column with the first 5 characters of COL_ID.   Put a non-unique index on it.  Put your search keys in a table and join that to that column.

There may be a way to do it with a functional index on the first 5 characters.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say "Generally the use of LIKE *on the left side* makes it impossible for Oracle to use indexes."  A simple index on col_id is probably good enough here.  More than that seems like premature optimization to me.

Comment: Interesting.   Why do you say that?

Comment: @EvilTeach Try it yourself. Run and see the execution plan of select. `create table t_test as select * from all_objects;
create index tt_indx on t_test(object_name);
select * from t_test t where t.object_name like 'I_OBJ%';` You will find little pretty `INDEX RANGE SCAN`. Put wildcard to the beginning `'%I_OBJ'` and it will be `TABLE ACCESS FULL`. So @jonearles is right, there is just a word missed in above statement. `Generally the use of LIKE *with wildcard* on the left side makes it impossible for Oracle to use indexes.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the performance will be better or not, but another way to write this is with a union:

```
select A.col1,B.col2,B.col3
  from table1 A,table2 B
  where A.col2=B.col2
  and (A.col_id like '12345%')
union all
select A.col1,B.col2,B.col3
  from table1 A,table2 B
  where A.col2=B.col2
  and (A.col_id like '47474%')  -- you did mean A.col_id again, right?
union all
select A.col1,B.col2,B.col3
  from table1 A,table2 B
  where A.col2=B.col2
  and (A.col_id like '59598%');  -- and A.col_id here too?
```

Comment: To match the logic of the question, you would need to use union all.

Comment: We cannot use union since because we might need to pass more values from time to time like more 10.